# Selecting row of table using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I know this is a big ask but I was wondering if anyone could help me select an item using scrapy?

I want to access the "average temperature" on the page linked below and I am really confused about how to do it. Normally I would use classes but here they haven't provided them.

http://www.southamptonweather.co.uk/wxhistory.php

Thank you as always,

Gus

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: hey thanks for this, I tried this but it didn't yield anything of use (I am sure it was my misreading abilities not the docs problem!)

Comment: How about this https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.xpath('//td[text()="Average temperature"]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract()
```

Will work for you.

Xpaths is generally more powerful than css selectors, but much longer to write as well (:
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what 'scrapy' is, but you can easily get items from a HTML table.

```
# find a specific table by table count
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www.southamptonweather.co.uk/wxhistory.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

Result:

```
[                             0                                                 1
 0   Mar 1 Average and Extremes                        Mar 1 Average and Extremes
 1          Average temperature                                             5.9°C
 2             Average humidity                                               69%
 3             Average dewpoint                                             0.6°C
 4            Average barometer                                          988.3 mb
 5            Average windspeed                                           6.9 mph
 6            Average gustspeed                                           9.7 mph
 7            Average direction                                        232° ( SW)
 8           Rainfall for month                                            2.8 mm
 9            Rainfall for year                                          267.4 mm
 10     Maximum rain per minute                    0.6 mm on day 01 at time 21:26
 11         Maximum temperature                     9.4°C on day 01 at time 14:49
 12         Minimum temperature                     3.6°C on day 01 at time 07:37
 13            Maximum humidity                       82% on day 01 at time 00:00
 14            Minimum humidity                       54% on day 01 at time 15:06
 15            Maximum pressure                  991.0 mb on day 01 at time 12:28
 16            Minimum pressure                  984.0 mb on day 01 at time 00:00
 17           Maximum windspeed                  17.3 mph on day 01 at time 10:45
 18          Maximum gust speed  28.8 mph from 225 °( SW) on day 01 at time 10:44
 19          Maximum heat index                     9.4°C on day 01 at time 14:49]
```

I'm not sure what you want to do at this point.  Maybe you want the entire table, and if so, you are done.  If you want a subset of data, just apply a filter to the dataframe.  One the data is encased in a dataframe, you can do all kinds of things, including reshaping the data, plotting the data, statistical or mathematical analysis, etc.